# Show tooltip if mouse enters a C# ListView's scrollbar

Tags: c#, listview, tooltip, scrollbar

I would like to show a tooltip, as soon as the mouse cursor enters the vertical scrollbar of a System.Windows.Forms.ListView. For a DataGridView it would be easy, as there is a reference to the scrollbars for which I could hanlde the MouseEnter/ MouseLeave events.

The MouseMove event of the ListView isn't even triggered, when the mouse is over the scrollbars. Is there any solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ControlWatcher class raises events when the mouse pointer enters or leaves a control which is being "watched". It allows you to catch mouse events of multiple controls, or stop catching these events.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public ToolTip toolTip { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        toolTip = new ToolTip();

        var watcher = new ControlWatcher();
        watcher.MouseEnter += watcher_MouseEnter;
        watcher.MouseLeave += watcher_MouseLeave;
        watcher.AddControl(listView1);
        watcher.StartListening();
    }

    void watcher_MouseEnter(Control control)
    {
        var pt = control.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        toolTip.Show("Super tooltip", control, pt);
    }

    void watcher_MouseLeave(Control control)
    {
        toolTip.Hide(control);

    }
}

public class ControlWatcher : IMessageFilter
{
    public event Action<Control> MouseEnter;
    public event Action<Control> MouseLeave;

    private Control lastControl;

    private List<Control> controls;

    public ControlWatcher()
    {
        controls = new List<Control>();
    }

    public void StartListening()
    {
        Application.AddMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public void StopListening()
    {
        Application.RemoveMessageFilter(this);
    }

    public void AddControl(Control c)
    {
        controls.Add(c);
    }

    private bool IsMouseOverControl(Control control)
    {
        var pt = control.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        var isOver = (pt.X >= 0 && pt.Y >= 0 && pt.X <= control.Width && pt.Y <= control.Height);
        return isOver;
    }

    private void OnMouseEnter(Control control)
    {
        if (MouseEnter != null)
            MouseEnter(control);
    }

    private void OnMouseLeave(Control control)
    {
        if (MouseLeave != null)
            MouseLeave(control);
    }

    public bool PreFilterMessage(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg != 675 && m.Msg!=512)
        {
            return false;
        }
        //the control under the cursor
        var actControl = controls.FirstOrDefault(IsMouseOverControl);

        if (lastControl != null && actControl == null)
        {
            OnMouseLeave(lastControl);
            lastControl = null;
            return false;
        }

        if (lastControl==null && actControl != null && actControl != lastControl)
        {
            lastControl = actControl;
            OnMouseEnter(actControl);
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Generally this is a good idea but as mentioned I need to detect if the mouse enters or leaves the scrollbar, not the whole ListView. So I tried to enhance the ControlWatcher and add a MouseMove event. But same as already mentioned above the event isn't raised when the mouse is over the scrollbar.

Comment: The MouseEnter and MouseLeave of the ControlWatcher should be fired if the mouse if over the scrollbar or is over the listview itself.

Comment: The events are fired if the mouse enters or leaves the ListView. But how to detect if the mouse is over the scrollbar or over the remaining part of the ListView?

Comment: var isOverScrollbar = (pt.X >= 0 && pt.Y >= 0 && pt.X <= control.Width && pt.Y <= control.Height)
                         && !control.ClientRectangle.Contains(pt);
var isOverRemainingPart=control.ClientRectangle.Contains(pt);

Comment: Thank you, this really seems to work now. I added a method 'IsMouseOverScrollbar' which now returns whether the mouse cursor is over the horizontal, the vertical or no scrollbar. I will add the code as a separate answer but accept your answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an addition to the accepted answer, here is the method I use to detect if the mouse is over the horizontal, the vertical or no scrollbar:

```
    private ScrollBars IsMouseOverScrollbar(ListView dlv)
    {
        var pt = dlv.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
        var isOverScrollbar = (pt.X >= 0 && pt.Y >= 0 && pt.X <= dlv.Width && pt.Y <= dlv.Height) && !dlv.ClientRectangle.Contains(pt);

        if (isOverScrollbar)
        {
            // the mouse is over some scrollbar
            if (dlv.Bounds.Width - pt.X > dlv.Bounds.Height - pt.Y)
            {
                // mouse pointer is within the horizontal scrollbar
                return ScrollBars.Horizontal;
            }
            else
            {
                // mouse pointer is within the vertical scrollbar
                return ScrollBars.Vertical;
            }
        }

        return ScrollBars.None;
    }
```